# Bash script not working when run outside terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnupg, zenity

This script does not function properly when launched graphically (by double clicking script icon and selecting run), however, runs just fine if called from the terminal; will not save a file or load contents from an existing file. Please help! Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script provides a simple and secure messaging system for users not
# familiar with gpg or using the terminal. The idea is to keep sensitive
# plaintext files off one's computer.

zenity --question --text="Select operation:" --ok-label="Compose" --cancel-label="Read"
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    usr=$(zenity --entry --text="Sender Key ID:")
    rec=$(zenity --entry --text="Recipient Key ID:")
    pwd=$(zenity --password)
    outfile=$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite)
    zenity --text-info --editable | gpg -aseu $usr -r $rec --passphrase $pwd --cipher-algo AES256 -o $outfile
else
    infile=$(zenity --file-selection)
    pwd=$(zenity --password)
    gpg -d --passphrase $pwd $infile | zenity --text-info --height=600 --width=800
fi
```

Comment: C'mon, you ought to know by now that "does not function properly" is not a diagnosis...

Comment: Sorry, I don't read minds on Tuesday.  You'll have to actually tell us what's not working.

Comment: Sorry. If the script is run by double-clicking it then choosing run, it executes but will not save a file or load contents from an existing file.

Comment: When you're in the terminal, you're cd'ing to a directory? (I'm guessing). How does the double-click run know which directory to be in? Also, you might want to add `set -vx` at the top to see debugging and trace info. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A probable cause for the error is that you have different environments when executing via an interactive shell (thus sourcing your `.bashrc`) and double-clicking (non-interactive, and not sourcing `.bashrc`

You can compare the environments by doing an `env > from_terminal` vs. `env > double_click` and then using `diff` or something similar.

You could also (after doing the above) source `from_terminal` in your script to see if it works with the terminal environment. As stated in one of the comments, `set -vx` is your friend.